# Uncompilable source code Error?

Tags: java, swing

I am getting this message when i am running my program. How can I correct this error? I marked that line said in message by comment!

message:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - 
>       Erroneous sym type: javax.swing.JPanel.add
>       at login.Login.frame(Login.java:52)
>       at login.Login.(Login.java:24)
>       at login.Login.main(Login.java:103)
>       BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 16 seconds)

and my code

```
package login;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.sql.*;


public class Login 
{

    Connection con;
    Statement st;
    ResultSet rs; 

    JFrame f = new JFrame("User login");
    JLabel l = new JLabel("Username:");
    JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Password:");
    JTextField t = new JTextField(10);
    JTextField t1 = new JTextField(10);
    JButton b = new JButton("login");


    public Login()
    {
        connect();
        frame(); //this line:at login.Login.<init>(Login.java:24)//

    }

    public void connect()
    {

        try 
        {
            String driver = "sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver";
            Class.forName(driver);

            String db = "jdbc:odbc:login";
            con = DriverManager.getConnection(db);   
            st = con.createStatement();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
        }
    }

    public void frame()
    {
        f.setSize(600,400);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);

        JPanel p = new JPanel();
        p.add(1);//this line:at login.Login.frame(Login.java:52)//
        p.add(t);
        p.add(11);
        p.add(t1);
        p.add(b);

        f.add(p);

        b.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try
                {
                    String user = t.getText().trim();
                    String pass = t1.getText().trim();  

                    String sql = "select user,pass from login where user = '"+user+"'and pass = '"+pass+"'";
                    rs = st.executeQuery(sql);

                    int count = 0;
                    while(rs.next())
                    {
                        count = count + 1;
                    }

                    if(count == 1)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User Found,Access Generated!");
                    }
                    else if(count > 1)
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Duplicate User,Access Denied!");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"User not Found");
                    }
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] arg) 
    {
        new Login(); //this line:at login.Login.main(Login.java:103)//``
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't try to run uncompilable code. What errors do you see when you try to *compile* the program?

Comment: i see this message:Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: javax.swing.JPanel.add at login.Login.frame(Login.java:52) at login.Login.(Login.java:24) at login.Login.main(Login.java:103) BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 16 seconds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Use better variable names, so people reading your code (including future you) can tell what's happening.
2. As Hovercraft Full Of Eels said in their comment, don't run uncompilable code. Compiler errors are... not your friends exactly, but they'll help you.
3. There are multiple .add() methods for JPanel, but none of them accept just an int as a parameter, which is what you have at login.Login.frame(Login.java:52) and then again two lines down from there, so that's what's causing your code not to compile. I think you actually meant l (el) and l1 (el one) instead of 1 (one) and 11 (eleven), which feeds back into #1 above: Use better variable names!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to add a number to a JPanel, and that doesn't make sense to the Java compiler (or to me). What are you trying to do with `myJPanel.add(1)` anyway?

Answer (score 1):

You need to put `'l'` ('L') instead of `'1'` -one

```
p.add(l);
p.add(l1);
```

as you have following labels to be added

```
JLabel l = new JLabel("Username:");
JLabel l1 = new JLabel("Password:");
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to add `Component` s to `Panel`.

If you want to add number try `add(new JLabel("1"))`

Comment: Yes you should use JLabel in Swing application and Label in AWT application. My mistake.